# Does Android data-binding support raw resources?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am currently trying to pass the resource id of a raw resource to a special View using the new Android data-binding mechanism. When I try something like this

```
...
    app:bufferedSvg="@{ViewModel.headerCollapsed ? @raw/header_expand : @raw/header_collapse}"
...
```

I get an error `<expr> expected, got '@'`. The raw resources exist and cannot be turned into another kind of resource as they contain SVG data.

Is this a bug of Android data binding or is this intended behaviour?

Comment: What does the setter method or bindable property for `bufferedSvg` look like?

Comment: I have written a Custom Setters using @BindingAdapter annotation who takes an int as input parameter. The View itself does not have this attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least I found a workaround meanwhile. Import the R class:

```
<data>
    <import type="com.yourdomain.R"/>
    <variable name="ViewModel" type="com.yourdomain.ViewModel"/>
</data>

...

<com.yourdomain.yourview

    ...

    app:bufferedSvg="@{ViewModel.yourchoice ? R.raw.raw_resource1 : R.raw.raw_resource2}"

    ...

/>
```

Hope this helps someone who runs into the same problem. Would still like to know whether the @-notation for raw resources is planned to be supported or not.